# Android 4 * 4 tic tac toe game

Tags: java, android, android-layout, game-engine

I am a beginner in Android. I have made a basic 3 by 3 tic tac toe game using code available on internet.

Now I want to make this game for 4*4 board. If you know the logic or algorithm or code for 4*4 tic tac toe please help me. Please help me. Below I have posted full source code.

Layout:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#242424"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:lines="1"
        android:padding="5sp"
        android:text="TicTacToe"
        android:textColor="#8eab27"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="25dip" />

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tlGrid"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:stretchColumns="*" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnGrid11"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:padding="7dip"
                android:text=""
                android:textColor="#242424"
                android:textSize="35dip"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnGrid12"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:padding="7dip"
                android:text=""
                android:textColor="#242424"
                android:textSize="35dip"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnGrid13"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:padding="7dip"
                android:text=""
                android:textColor="#242424"
                android:textSize="35dip"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnGrid21"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:padding="7dip"
                android:text=""
                android:textColor="#242424"
                android:textSize="35dip"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnGrid22"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:padding="7dip"
                android:text=""
                android:textColor="#242424"
                android:textSize="35dip"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnGrid23"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:padding="7dip"
                android:text=""
                android:textColor="#242424"
                android:textSize="35dip"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnGrid31"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:padding="7dip"
                android:text=""
                android:textColor="#242424"
                android:textSize="35dip"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnGrid32"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:padding="7dip"
                android:text=""
                android:textColor="#242424"
                android:textSize="35dip"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnGrid33"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:padding="7dip"
                android:text=""
                android:textColor="#242424"
                android:textSize="35dip"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnReset"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_span="3"
                android:padding="7dip"
                android:text=""
                android:textColor="#242424"
                android:textSize="20dip"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

JAVA source code:

```
public class TicTacToe extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

private int[][] GridID = new int[4][4]; // i.e. [0 to 3][0 to 3]

private enum GridCode {
    BLANK, X, O
};

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Button button;
    int id;
    for (int r = 1; r <= 3; r++) {
        for (int c = 1; c <= 3; c++) {
            id = getResources().getIdentifier("btnGrid" + r + c, "id",
                    getPackageName());
            GridID[r][c] = id;
            button = (Button) findViewById(id);
            button.setText(""); // seems to be needed
            button.setOnClickListener(this);
        }
    }

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnReset);
    button.setText("");
    button.setOnClickListener(this);
}

private boolean gameHasEnded() {
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnReset);
    return button.getText() != "";
}

private void resetGrid() {
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnReset);
    button.setText("");
    for (int r = 1; r <= 3; r++) {
        for (int c = 1; c <= 3; c++) {
            button = (Button) findViewById(GridID[r][c]);
            button.setText("");
        }
    }

}

public void onClick(View v) {
    Button button = (Button) v;

    if (button == (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnReset)) {
        if (gameHasEnded())
            resetGrid();
        return;
    }

    if (gameHasEnded() || button.getText() != "")
        return;

    button.setText("X");

    int xCountByRow[] = new int[4];
    int oCountByRow[] = new int[4];
    int xCountByColumn[] = new int[4];
    int oCountByColumn[] = new int[4];
    int xCountByDiagonal[] = new int[3];
    int oCountByDiagonal[] = new int[3];

    GridCode gc[][] = new GridCode[4][4];

    for (int r = 1; r <= 3; r++) {
        for (int c = 1; c <= 3; c++) {
            button = (Button) findViewById(GridID[r][c]);
            if (button.getText() == "X") {
                gc[r][c] = GridCode.X;
                xCountByRow[r]++;
                xCountByColumn[c]++;
                if (r == c)
                    xCountByDiagonal[1]++;
                if (r + c == 4)
                    xCountByDiagonal[2]++;
            } else if (button.getText() == "O") {
                gc[r][c] = GridCode.O;
                oCountByRow[r]++;
                oCountByColumn[c]++;
                if (r == c)
                    oCountByDiagonal[1]++;
                if (r + c == 4)
                    oCountByDiagonal[2]++;
            } else {
                gc[r][c] = GridCode.BLANK;
            }
        }
    }

    // Have we lost?
    for (int r = 1; r <= 3; r++) {
        if (xCountByRow[r] == 3) {
            declareLoss();
            return;
        }
    }
    for (int c = 1; c <= 3; c++) {
        if (xCountByColumn[c] == 3) {
            declareLoss();
            return;
        }
    }
    for (int d = 1; d <= 2; d++) {
        if (xCountByDiagonal[d] == 3) {
            declareLoss();
            return;
        }
    }

    // Can we win?
    for (int r = 1; r <= 3; r++) {
        if (oCountByRow[r] == 2 && xCountByRow[r] == 0) {
            for (int c = 1; c <= 3; c++) {
                if (gc[r][c] == GridCode.BLANK) {
                    button = (Button) findViewById(GridID[r][c]);
                    button.setText("O");
                    declareWin();
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    for (int c = 1; c <= 3; c++) {
        if (oCountByColumn[c] == 2 && xCountByColumn[c] == 0) {
            for (int r = 1; r <= 3; r++) {
                if (gc[r][c] == GridCode.BLANK) {
                    button = (Button) findViewById(GridID[r][c]);
                    button.setText("O");
                    declareWin();
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    for (int d = 1; d <= 2; d++) {
        if (oCountByDiagonal[d] == 2 && xCountByDiagonal[d] == 0) {
            for (int r = 1; r <= 3; r++) {
                int c = (d == 1) ? r : 4 - r;
                if (gc[r][c] == GridCode.BLANK) {
                    button = (Button) findViewById(GridID[r][c]);
                    button.setText("O");
                    declareWin();
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Do we need to block a win?
    for (int r = 1; r <= 3; r++) {
        if (xCountByRow[r] == 2 && oCountByRow[r] == 0) {
            for (int c = 1; c <= 3; c++) {
                if (gc[r][c] == GridCode.BLANK) {
                    button = (Button) findViewById(GridID[r][c]);
                    button.setText("O");
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    for (int c = 1; c <= 3; c++) {
        if (xCountByColumn[c] == 2 && oCountByColumn[c] == 0) {
            for (int r = 1; r <= 3; r++) {
                if (gc[r][c] == GridCode.BLANK) {
                    button = (Button) findViewById(GridID[r][c]);
                    button.setText("O");
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    for (int d = 1; d <= 2; d++) {
        if (xCountByDiagonal[d] == 2 && oCountByDiagonal[d] == 0) {
            for (int r = 1; r <= 3; r++) {
                int c = (d == 1) ? r : 4 - r;
                if (gc[r][c] == GridCode.BLANK) {
                    button = (Button) findViewById(GridID[r][c]);
                    button.setText("O");
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // TODO:
    // Can we create a double threat?
    // Do we need to prevent a double threat?

    // Move randomly
    Button buttons[] = new Button[9];
    int buttonCount = 0;
    for (int r = 1; r <= 3; r++) {
        for (int c = 1; c <= 3; c++) {
            if (gc[r][c] == GridCode.BLANK) {
                buttonCount++;
                buttons[buttonCount] = (Button) findViewById(GridID[r][c]);
            }
        }
    }
    if (buttonCount == 0) {
        declareDraw();
        return;
    }
    Random random = new Random();
    Button randomButton = buttons[random.nextInt(buttonCount) + 1];
    randomButton.setText("O");
}

private void declareSomething(String something) {
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnReset);
    button.setText(something + "! \n(click to reset)");
}

private void declareLoss() {
    declareSomething("Congratulations! You win");
}

private void declareWin() {
    declareSomething("You Lose!Computer Win");
}

private void declareDraw() {
    declareSomething("Draw");
}
```

}

Comment: So you took some code from the Internet and you want us to extend it for you? Please come back with a _specific_ question and what you have, personally, attempted. You will not learn anything if you are just spoonfed the answers.

Comment: Very sorry but no. We can help you with specific problems you encounter on the way but we can't write the whole thing for you.

Comment: Not a real question. Poster is asking to write or correct the whole code of application. He has not tried it and doesn't have any problem which we can help him to solve.

Comment: Also you should start by just increasing the loops by 1 and see where that gets you for your 4*4 grid, as others said as well you need to know more than copy n paste to make a game you will need to know the android framework and basic game mechanics. Debugging will be vital.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to develop a game for android, and you say you are a complete beginner. Well to make an android game (and not just copy code from the net) you need to be at least somewhat familiar with 3 things: 1) java in general, 2) game development, 3) android.

Your question is way to broad and general for anyone here to answer really, I suggest you look for some beginner tutorials for the specific area you want to get better at.